# DataStax agent 6.5 not connecting to DSE cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I have installed a DSE 6.0 cassandra cluster using LCM| opscenter 6.5 and node is up is running . During LCM cluster install, it installed datastax agent as well . 
But the agent is not connecting to DSE and opscenter is not showing any details about the node.Later I tried with tarball install of datastax agent but that too is showing same issue. Please see below agent.log and screenshots.

```
  WARN [async-dispatch-2] 2018-07-24 09:23:19,915 JMX marked as down, restarting JMX components.
 ERROR [async-dispatch-2] 2018-07-24 09:23:19,916 Error starting DynamicEnvrionmentComponent.
 java.io.IOException: Process failed: bash -c /tmp/opsc_3882111672138551416/dense.sh
  Exit val: 126
  Output:
bash: /tmp/opsc_3882111672138551416/dense.sh: Permission denied
        at opsagent.proc$handle_proc_results.invokeStatic(proc.clj:61)
        at opsagent.proc$handle_proc_results.invoke(proc.clj:51)
        at opsagent.proc$run_proc.invokeStatic(proc.clj:84)
        at opsagent.proc$run_proc.doInvoke(proc.clj:65)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
        at opsagent.environment.utils$package_config_paths.invokeStatic(utils.clj:161)
        at opsagent.environment.utils$package_config_paths.invoke(utils.clj:141)
        at opsagent.environment.utils$all_config_paths.invokeStatic(utils.clj:197)
        at opsagent.environment.utils$all_config_paths.doInvoke(utils.clj:190)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:805)
        at opsagent.environment.dynamic$dynamic_env_state.invokeStatic(dynamic.clj:162)
        at opsagent.environment.dynamic$dynamic_env_state.invoke(dynamic.clj:148)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:171)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:652)
        at clojure.core$partial$fn__4765.doInvoke(core.clj:2534)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
        at opsagent.jmx$create_jmx_pool_with_config$wrapper__5941.doInvoke(jmx.clj:239)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
        at opsagent.environment.dynamic$add_dynamic_state.invokeStatic(dynamic.clj:276)
        at opsagent.environment.dynamic$add_dynamic_state.invoke(dynamic.clj:264)
        at opsagent.environment.dynamic.DynamicEnvironmentComponent.start(dynamic.clj:299)
        at com.stuartsierra.component$fn__2593$G__2587__2595.invoke(component.clj:4)
        at com.stuartsierra.component$fn__2593$G__2586__2598.invoke(component.clj:4)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:641)
        at com.stuartsierra.component$try_action.invokeStatic(component.clj:116)
        at com.stuartsierra.component$try_action.invoke(component.clj:115)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:401)
        at opsagent.config_service$update_system$fn__22445.invoke(config_service.clj:223)
        at clojure.lang.ArraySeq.reduce(ArraySeq.java:114)
        at clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic(core.clj:6544)
        at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6527)
        at opsagent.config_service$update_system.invokeStatic(config_service.clj:217)
        at opsagent.config_service$update_system.doInvoke(config_service.clj:213)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
        at opsagent.config_service$start_system_BANG_.invokeStatic(config_service.clj:243)
        at opsagent.config_service$start_system_BANG_.invoke(config_service.clj:236)
        at opsagent.config_service$fn__22551$fn__22552$state_machine__4942__auto____22553$fn__22555.invoke(config_service.clj:266)
        at opsagent.config_service$fn__22551$fn__22552$state_machine__4942__auto____22553.invoke(config_service.clj:266)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:973)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:972)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:977)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:975)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$take_BANG_$fn__4958.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:986)
        at clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel$fn__707$fn__708.invoke(channels.clj:95)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 INFO [async-dispatch-2] 2018-07-24 09:23:19,917 Starting JMXComponent
```

[image: error in opscenter]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please note "/tmp/opsc_3882111672138551416/dense.sh: Permission denied" in your logs.

You probably don't have permissions to create anything under /tmp/

You can try fix the permissions or to reconfigure your temporary directory with -Djava.io.tmpdir in datastax-agent-env.sh:
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xmx128M -Djava.io.tmpdir=/other/temp/directory"

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here: `/usr/share/datastax-agent/bin/`

In version 6, there is `datastax-agent` instead of `datastax-agent-env.sh`

Remember to add this line at the beggining of datastax-agent file